# Does having infinite limits at a point of discontinuity imply having a vertical asymptote?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Considering that discontinuities occur at holes, jumps, and vertical asymptotes. Is it possible for a function to have a limit from the left of infinite and the limit from the right - infinite if the number that is being approached is NOT the location of a vertical asymptote?

Comment: To answer this, one needs a *precise* definition of "vertical asymptote".

Comment: Going to infinity vertically at a point is pretty much the definition of vertical asymptote. But in higher math courses all sorts of funny things can happen, which you might be visualizing already but not knowing how to describe.